# Conversion with _itoa

Tags: c

Conversion of values in structure with _itoa in example below is not successful. Do anybody see any mistake I made?

```
/*
typedef struct struct_rect
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int w;
  int h;
}rectangle;

struct struct_objects
{
  int sort;
  rectangle rect;
  ALLEGRO_COLOR color;
}objects[1000];

int number_of_objects = 2;
*/

bool print_objects()
{
  char value_string[100];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < number_of_objects; i++)
  {
    memset(value_string, '\0', sizeof(value_string));
    _itoa(objects[i].sort, value_string, 30);   
    printf("%i x %s\n", objects[i].sort, value_string);

    memset(value_string, '\0', sizeof(value_string));
    _itoa(objects[i].rect.x, value_string, 30); 
    printf("%i x %s\n", objects[i].rect.x, value_string);

    memset(value_string, '\0', sizeof(value_string));
    _itoa(objects[i].rect.y, value_string, 30); 
    printf("%i x %s\n", objects[i].rect.y, value_string);

    memset(value_string, '\0', sizeof(value_string));
    _itoa(objects[i].rect.w, value_string, 30); 
    printf("%i x %s\n", objects[i].rect.w, value_string);

    memset(value_string, '\0', sizeof(value_string));
    _itoa(objects[i].rect.h, value_string, 30); 
    printf("%i x %s\n", objects[i].rect.h, value_string);
  }

return true;
}
```

output is(values in left column are correct, in right column not):

> 0 x 0
>  20 x k
>  50 x 1k
>  50 x 1k
>  50 x 1k
>
> 0 x 0
>  150 x 50
>  300 x a0
>  20 x k
>  200 x 6k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is correct. You are getting result in base<sub>30</sub>.

For ex: In base<sub>30</sub>, [300<sub>10</sub> = a0<sub>30</sub>](http://www.efunda.com/units/base_n.cfm?base_from=30).

[Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx) of function `_itoa` are:

1. Number to be converted
2. Destination string
3. Radix

You are giving your radix as 30, so the output is printed at base 30.

You should call the function as:

```
_itoa(objects[i].sort, value_string, 10);
```

to get the decimal output.

It is quite easy to get confused with 3<sup>rd</sup> and assume it is size o string for first time users of this function. To avoid such consequences, prefer `sprintf`

```
sprintf(value_string, "%d", objects[i].sort);
```